# Task D. Calc3:Squares. how to construct a proper loop for my assignment? C++

Tags: c++, project

I need help with a coding assignment.

Write an even better calculator program calc3.cpp(Using **iostream** only) that can understand squared numbers. We are going to use a simplified notation X^ to mean X^2. For example, 10^ + 7 - 51^ should mean 10^2 + 7 − 51^2.
Example:
When reading input file **formulas.txt**

```
5^;
1000 + 6^ - 5^ + 1;
15^+15^;
```

the program should report:

```
$ ./calc3 < formulas.txt
25
1012
50625
```

A hint:
To take into account ^, don’t add or subtract new numbers right away after reading them. Instead, remember the number, read the next operator and if it is a ^, square the remembered number, then add or subtract it.

**What I have so far:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
int numbers,firstnum;
char operators ; // for storing -+;^ from the txt file
int sum = 0;
cin >> firstnum; // stores the 1st integer of the expression found in the txt file. 
while(cin >> operators >> numbers)
 { // while loop for storing characters and int 

    if(numbers>=0 and operators =='+')//adding
    {
        firstnum+=numbers;
    }
    else if (numbers>=0 and operators == '-')//subtracting
    {
        firstnum-=numbers;
    }
    if (operators==';') // semicolon:ends the loop for each expression
    {
    cout<<firstnum<<'\n';
    firstnum=0+numbers;
    }

 }  
sum=firstnum; // for the last expression not picked up by the while-loop
cout<<sum;

}
```

I need help constructing a while loop so the '^' doesn't break the loop.

Comment: Parsing tips; it might be easier to read in the file line by line as your data file has a `;` as its terminator or delimiter. Read the line and save it into a `std::string`. From there have a function that will parse each string. If the data is extracted as a string you can search through the string character by character looking for tokens.

Comment: @FrancisCugler unfortunately my professor does not want us using this method because it involves utilizing codes that he hasn't covered in lecture as of now(thats why i am strictly using iostream).

Comment: I understand the restrictions. I just didn't think std::string would of been an issue.

Comment: [This is the third question here concerning this assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49101652/calculator-that-accepts-multiple-inputs-like-and-number-squared-pulling-i).  Where are the teacher's assistants in your school?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I noticed 2... must of been another added since.

Answer (score 0):

In the terminology of parsing, `^` has higher precedence than `+` and `-`. That is, `^` must be applied first before additions and subtractions are evaluated. You shouldn't add/subtract a number before knowing whether the next token after the number is a `^`; because if it is, then you need to perform the squaring operation first.

Consider, for example, the following input file:

```
1 + 3^;
```

Right now, your program will read `1` and store this in `firstnum`. Then your program reads `+` (storing this in `operators`) and `3` (storing this in `numbers`). Then your program reaches the `numbers>=0 and operators =='+'` case, so `firstnum+=numbers;` is evaluated and `firstnum` becomes 4. But, this is a mistake, because the next token is a `^`, so the 3 should have been squared first.

Consider this other example:

```
4^ + 1;
```

Your program currently reads `4` into `firstnum`, `^` into `operators`, and then tries to parse `+` as an integer. This fails, causing the fail bit to be set on `cin` and `cin >> operators >> numbers` evaluates to `false`.

One special case that you might want to handle is when an expression begins with a `-`:

```
-9^;
-10^ + 11^;
```

Also, you might want to ask for clarification as to how the following should be handled:

```
1^ + -2^;
1^ - -2^;
2^^^;
```