# Calculator that accepts multiple inputs like +, -, and number squared. Pulling info from text file

Tags: c++

My code is supposed to be able to print multiple different equations in one text file with the `;` character causing the equation to stop and go to the next line, and the `^` character taking the number squared. However, the code only prints one equation then stops. I was told that I needed a loop over my already established loop. I don't know how I can do this though. Thank you.

INPUT

```
    5^ + 5 - 4^;
    2 - 1;
    1 + 5^ + 2;
```

MY OUTPUT

```
    14
```

MY CODE

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <math.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

char op;
int result, operand;


int readnumber();

int readnumber()
{
    int val;
    cin >> val;
    if (cin.peek() == '^')
    { // found ^
        val *= val; 
        cin.ignore(); 
    }

    return val;
}

int main() {

    result = readnumber(); 
    while (cin >> op) {

    if (op == ';') {
        cout << result << endl; 
        cin >> result;
    } 

    operand = readnumber();

    if (op == '+') {
        result += operand;
       }

    if (op == '-') {
        result -= operand;
    }


    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Have you used a debugger to track what's happening on the second equation?

Comment: No, all I have is the Ubuntu terminal...

Comment: This is a good time to learn how to use gdb.  I'd suggest giving that a try and updating this question with the results.

Comment: The results seemed fine to me, I know it's because of some delimited loop. I don't understand why the while loops stops after the `;`

Comment: Why all the esoteric reading?  Just read the entire input into a string, and parse the string.  BTW, this question about this same homework assignment has been asked already on stack overflow at least 4 times.

Comment: maybe this could help you out http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/calculator08buggy.cpp from Stroustrup him self.

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49119762/196844

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to read a number after you print the result (`cin >> result;`).  By deleting that line I can add more items (although the results seem incorrect).

Comment: Yes, I deleted that as well. Although it seems that now the program takes the result and replaces that with the first number of the next line...