# How square numbers from an input file

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a program where I have a .txt file and read that file with my program. My program should be able to add or subtract the numbers and display the sum. I have currently gotten to the point where I can successfuly add or subtract the numbers in a file. The problem I have arises when I try to take the square of a number. For example this is what the text file could look like.

8^;

6^ + 3;

900 + 5^ - 4^ + 2 - 9;

The desired out put should look like this

64

39

902

So far I am just able to process the answer when there is no squaring involved. But when I include the squaring everything becoming confusing. If someone can help me down the right path towards the solution I would be greatly appreciative.

```
int main() {
//Initialize variables
int sum = 0;
char operation;
int number;
int holdingnumber;
int holdingoperation;
int operationChecker;
ifstream fileChecker;

//Open file
fileChecker.open("data.txt");

//If file didn't open exit program
if (!fileChecker) {
    cout << "The file could not be found/opened!";
    exit(1);
}

//Read information from file and add to variable sum
fileChecker >> number;
sum = number;
while (fileChecker >> operation >> number)
{
    if (operation == ';')
    {
        cout << sum << endl;
        sum = number;
    }
    else if (operation == '^')
    {
        holdingnumber = holdingnumber * holdingnumber;
        if (holdingoperation == '+')
        {
            sum = sum + holdingnumber;
        }
        else if (holdingoperation == '-')
        {
            sum = sum - holdingoperation;
        }
    }
    else if (operation == '+')
    {
        holdingoperation = operation;
        holdingnumber = number;
    }
    else if (operation == '-')
    {
        holdingoperation = operation;
        holdingnumber = number;
    }
}

//Close file and display sum
fileChecker.close();
cout << sum;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: *If someone can help me down the right path towards the solution I would be greatly appreciative.* -- Use the debugger that comes with your compiler toolset.

Comment: [Same homework assignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49101652/calculator-that-accepts-multiple-inputs-like-and-number-squared-pulling-i)

Comment: It helps to specify exactly what error you are getting and to provide a minimal and complete example of code that demonstrates the error and what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Right out of the gate, `while (fileChecker >> operation >> number)`, fails. See [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt). So you can't assume the input. I'm baffled by this assignment. Ether the professor failed or you failed to get vital information from the lectures.

Comment: There are at least 3 other questions on stack overflow posted within the last hour concerning this very same homework assignment.  The same strange input mechanism of chaining `>>` is used in all of those posts.  Why not break away from the pack and just read the string into one variable, and parse the string?  If you don't, and you get an answer from those other posts, you may be docked for plagiarism if you just copy what the others have been told to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you are (or will) run into your biggest problem is due to the fact that you have created a very fragile input routine that relies on `>> number >> operator` format of the input file. Why you are having problems implementing the *squared* part of the code is the input format regarding the square with additional calculation doesn't simply follow `>> number >> operator`, but also includes `>> operator >> number`.

For example:

```
900 + 5^ - 4^ + 2 - 9;
```

is `>> number >> operator >> number >> operator >> operator >> number operator >> operator >> number >> operator >> number >> delimiter`.

While you will have nested conditionals regardless how you do it, the number required quickly gets out of hand when you start adding additional conditionals to your read statement in addition to handling the various calculations based on them.

In your code above, if you change `>>` to `scanf` calls and `<<` to `printf`, your code does not make use of anything C++ offers. C++ provides a good set of tools that can help you work with values, strings, characters, and collections of those things. Take advantage of what the language provides.

Here, using the `string` and `vector` classes, eliminates having to manage your `holding...` variables. It can do so while completely eliminating your dependence that a delimiter (e.g. `';'`) be present at the end of the line. (in fact the only challenge there is if you find a line delimited by a `';'`, you simply remove it)

A better approach for reading your file is to read a line at a time into a `string` with `getline`. This makes looping over you file a simple matter of reading each line into a string until there are no more lines to read.

C++ provides auto ranged iterators (along with severall others), that then let you iterate over each character in you string (line). The `<cctype>` header provides the `isdigit()` function allowing you to determine if the current char is a digit allowing you to obtain the numeric values. The `vector` class makes it easy to then store that value (and as many more as required), by simply calling the `push_back()` member function to add that value to your vector.

(note: you can just as easily use a *stringstream* on the stored string and parse the values that way if you like with conversion routines like `stoi`, but for simple numbers (which are presumed non-negative -- meaning `'-'` is an operator and code is not included to deal with `'- -value'`, but that could easily be added)

When an operator is encountered, the vector class provides a simple `.size()` member function allowing you to tell how many values are waiting in your vector. Then it is just a logic game of knowing that `+, -, *, /` will operate on last *adjacent* values in the vector, while `'^'` will operate only on the last.

If you leave the last value in your vector always holding the current `sum`, then you don't have to track any other variables (except for temporary use) while working through all the computations on a given line.

When you are done processing a line, you have the text of the calculation already stored in your string, so after you process a line, all you need do is output your calculation string and then the result (the last value stored in your vector):

```
cout << string << " = " << vector.back() << "\n";
```

Putting all the pieces together, you could do something similar to the following. With a little more thought, you can probably find a much better way to do it. The point being, there will always be many ways to approach a problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cctype>

using std::ifstream;
using std::cout;
using std::cerr;
using std::string;
using std::vector;

/* execute current calculation between adjacent values */
void execute (vector<long>& values, char op);

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    long tmp = 0;   /* temp number to build values as chars processed */
    string calc;    /* string to hold the line (complete calculation) */
    ifstream f (argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "data.txt");   /* file to read */

    if (!f.is_open()) { /* validate file open for reading */
        cerr << "error: file open failed.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    while (getline (f, calc)) {     /* loop over each line in the file */
        char op = 0;                /* char to hold operator (+,-,*,/) */
        vector<long> values;        /* vector to hold adjacent values */
        if (calc.back() == ';')     /* if line delimited by ';', then */
            calc.pop_back();        /* remove ';' from string */
        for (auto& c : calc) {      /* for each char in line */
            if (isdigit(c)) {       /* am I a digit?, if so build value */
                tmp *= 10;
                tmp += c - '0';
            }
            else {  /* if I'm not a digit, I'm either whitespace or op */
                if (tmp) {              /* if there is a value in temp */
                    values.push_back (tmp); /* add the value to vector */
                    tmp = 0;                /* zero tmp */
                }
                if (values.size() && c == '^') {     /* handle squared */
                    values.back() *= values.back();  /* square in place */  
                }
                else if (values.size() > 1 && op) { /* adjacent vals & op */
                    execute (values, op);   /* computer intermediate calc */
                    op = 0;                 /* op consumed, reset to zero */
                }
                else {  /* not digit, not squaring, no adjacent vales */
                    switch (c) {    /* save op if one of following */
                        case '+':   op = c; break;
                        case '-':   op = c; break;
                        case '*':   op = c; break;
                        case '/':   op = c; break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }   /* all characters processed */
        if (tmp) {                      /* does tmp value remain? */
            values.push_back (tmp);     /* add to vector */
            tmp = 0;                    /* reset tmp */
        }
        if (values.size() > 1 && op)    /* handle final calculation */
            execute (values, op);
        cout << calc << " = " << values.back() << "\n";
    }
    f.close();
}

/* simple function takes vector reference and operator
 * and performs indicated calculation on adjacent values.
 */
void execute (vector<long>& values, char op)
{
    long sum;
    auto it = values.end();
    it -= 2;
    switch (op) {
        case '+':   sum = *it + values.back();
                    values.pop_back();
                    values.back() = sum; 
                    break;
        case '-':   sum = *it - values.back();
                    values.pop_back();
                    values.back() = sum; 
                    break;
        case '*':   sum = *it * values.back();
                    values.pop_back();
                    values.back() = sum; 
                    break;
        case '/':   sum = *it / values.back();
                    values.pop_back();
                    values.back() = sum; 
                    break;
    }
}
```

(**note:** the use of `pop_back()` above as well to trim the last element from the vector allowing you to leave your running total as the final (and only) value in the vector. Essentially, the calculations are done, and if it involved two values, after the calculation is done, the last value in the vector is removed and the current total is stored in place of the first value to that calculation)

Also note, this was a simple example and isn't intended for anything other than addressing an approach for your input data file.

**Example Input Files**

Without end of line delimiters:

```
$ cat ../dat/calc.txt
127 + 231
8^
6^ + 3
900 + 5^ - 4^ + 2 - 9
```

With delimiters:

```
$ cat ../dat/calcdelim.txt
127 + 231;
8^;
6^ + 3;
900 + 5^ - 4^ + 2 - 9;
```

**Example Use/Output**

Output is the same regardless of which input file is used.

```
$ ./bin/calctest ../dat/calc.txt
127 + 231 = 358
8^ = 64
6^ + 3 = 39
900 + 5^ - 4^ + 2 - 9 = 902
```

Look things over. It takes time to digest the different parts of the language. That is were a number of good reference cites help, like [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp). Let me know if you have any additional questions.